# Is it possible to make this query in ONE unique query: all observations for every patient with certain condition?

Tags: hl7-fhir

we are developing an statistics module, based on fhir messaging, which receives a query about making certain statistics for group of patients with certain attributes like age, location, conditions, etc. . For example, we want to make statistics about observations in a period for certain group of patients in an area with certain condition.

is it possible to make only one query rest api for this: observations for patients with certain condition? I  have tried certain queries with chained and compartment features, but i cannot get it.

I will appreciate any help for any master of making Fhir queries. If not, I know that  i can join different queries in a _named query.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is not presently possible.

We've done chaining :[find all conditions where the subject it refers to has a property]. 
What this needs is reverse chaining: [find all patients where a condition that refers to it has a property]

This is a candidate for a future version